# Python - HTTP multipart/form-data POST request

Tags: python, python-3.x

I would like to upload a file to a web server. From what I have read, the best way to do this is to use the multipart/form-data encoding type on an HTTP POST request.

My research seems to indicate that there is no simple way to do this using the Python standard library. I am using Python 3.

(Note: see a package called [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) ([PyPI Link](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/requests)) to easily accomplish this)

I am currently using this method:

```
import mimetypes, http.client
boundary = 'wL36Yn8afVp8Ag7AmP8qZ0SA4n1v9T' # Randomly generated
for fileName in fileList:
    # Add boundary and header
    dataList.append('--' + boundary)
    dataList.append('Content-Disposition: form-data; name={0}; filename={0}'.format(fileName))

    fileType = mimetypes.guess_type(fileName)[0] or 'application/octet-stream'
    dataList.append('Content-Type: {}'.format(fileType))
    dataList.append('')

    with open(fileName) as f: 
        # Bad for large files
        dataList.append(f.read())

dataList.append('--'+boundary+'--')
dataList.append('')
contentType = 'multipart/form-data; boundary={}'.format(boundary)

body = '\r\n'.join(dataList)
headers = {'Content-type': contentType}

conn = http.client.HTTPConnection('http://...')
req = conn.request('POST', '/test/', body, headers)

print(conn.getresponse().read())
```

This works to send text.

There are two issues: This is text only, and the whole text file must be stored in memory as a giant string.

How can I upload any binary file?  Is there a way to do this without reading the whole file into memory?

Comment: You should REALLY use the requests package you mentioned already. There is a lot of stuff which is not handled by the standard library, like session management, authentication, checking SSL certificates, ... What's your reason for not using the request module?

Comment: You could just copy code out of the requests module that does what you need.

Comment: It's of course your decission. But if I can choose between packaging a high quality, well tested, "mission proved", ... library or my own custom code, I would always choose the first one. ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a look at this module

```
class HTTPConnection:
    # ...
    def send(self, data): # line 820
        """Send `data' to the server.
        ``data`` can be a string object, a bytes object, an array object, a
        file-like object that supports a .read() method, or an iterable object.
        """
```

data is exactly body.
You may pass an iterator like this: (I did not try it out)

```
def body():
  for fileName in fileList:
    # Add boundary and header
    yield('--' + boundary) + '\r\n'
    yield('Content-Disposition: form-data; name={0}; filename=    {0}'.format(fileName)) + '\r\n'

    fileType = mimetypes.guess_type(fileName)[0] or 'application/octet-stream'
    yield('Content-Type: {}'.format(fileType)) + '\r\n'
    yield('\r\n')

    with open(fileName) as f: 
        # Bad for large files
        yield f.read()
    yield('--'+boundary+'--') + '\r\n'
    yield('') + '\r\n'
```

Comment: This is a good idea, and works with a few modifications in 3.2 or 3.3.  If an iterable is given to `HTTPConnection.request` or `HTTPConnection.send` then the content-length header also must be specified.  
However, I am using Python 3.1. Perhaps it is not feasible.

Comment: What problem do you get with python 3.1?

Comment: In 3.1 `body` cannot be an iterable. We actually have moved away from 3.1, so this answers my question.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at small [Doug Hellmann's urllib2](https://github.com/ivanromanko/yadmin/blob/master/lib/multipart_sender.py), translated by me to python3.

I use it nearly this way:

```
import urllib.request
import urllib.parse
from lib.multipart_sender import MultiPartForm

myfile = open('path/to/file', 'rb')
form = MultiPartForm()
form.add_field('token', apipost[mycgi['domain']]._token)
form.add_field('domain', mycgi['domain'])
form.add_file('file', 'logo.jpg', fileHandle=myfile)
form.make_result()

url = 'http://myurl'
req1 = urllib.request.Request(url)
req1.add_header('Content-type', form.get_content_type())
req1.add_header('Content-length', len(form.form_data))
req1.add_data(form.form_data)
fp = urllib.request.urlopen(req1)
print(fp.read()) # to view status
```

Comment: Thank you, but the idea is to use the standard library.

Answer (score -2):

You can use unirest to make the call. Sample code

```
import unirest

# consume async post request
def consumePOSTRequestSync():
 params = {'test1':'param1','test2':'param2'}

 # we need to pass a dummy variable which is open method
 # actually unirest does not provide variable to shift between
 # application-x-www-form-urlencoded and
 # multipart/form-data
 params['dummy'] = open('dummy.txt', 'r')
 url = 'http://httpbin.org/post'
 headers = {"Accept": "application/json"}
 # call get service with headers and params
 response = unirest.post(url, headers = headers,params = params)
 print "code:"+ str(response.code)
 print "******************"
 print "headers:"+ str(response.headers)
 print "******************"
 print "body:"+ str(response.body)
 print "******************"
 print "raw_body:"+ str(response.raw_body)

# post sync request multipart/form-data
consumePOSTRequestSync()
```

Check out the blog post for more details http://stackandqueue.com/?p=57