# Convert a PDF to DOCX using Adobe PDF Services via REST API (with Python)

Tags: python, httprequest, adobe, rest, adobe-pdfservices

I am trying to query Adobe PDF services API to generate (export) DOCX from PDF documents.

I just wrote a python code to generate a *Bearer Token* in order to be identified from *Adobe PDF services* (see the question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68351955/tunning-a-post-request-to-reach-adobe-pdf-services-using-python-and-a-rest-api). Then I wrote the following piece of code, where I tried to follow the instruction in this page concerning the `EXPORT` option of Adobe PDF services (here: https://documentcloud.adobe.com/document-services/index.html#post-exportPDF).

Here is the piece of code :

```
import requests
import json
from requests.structures import CaseInsensitiveDict
```

###### N/B: I didn't write the part of the code generating the Token and enabling identification by the server

###### >> This part is a POST request to upload my PDF file via form parameters

```
URL = "https://cpf-ue1.adobe.io/ops/:create?respondWith=%257B%2522reltype%2522%253A%2520%2522http%253A%252F%252Fns.adobe.com%252Frel%252Fprimary%2522%257D"

headers = CaseInsensitiveDict()
headers["x-api-key"] = "client_id"
headers["Authorization"] = "Bearer MYREALLYLONGTOKENIGOT"
headers["Content-Type"] = "application/json"

myfile = {"file":open("absolute_path_to_the_pdf_file/input.pdf", "rb")}

j="""
{
  "cpf:engine": {
    "repo:assetId": "urn:aaid:cpf:Service-26c7fda2890b44ad9a82714682e35888"
  },
  "cpf:inputs": {
    "params": {
      "cpf:inline": {
        "targetFormat": "docx"
      }
    },
    "documentIn": {
      "dc:format": "application/pdf",
      "cpf:location": "C:/Users/a-bensghir/Downloads/P_D_F/trs_pdf_file_copy.pdf"
    }
  },
  "cpf:outputs": {
    "documentOut": {
      "dc:format": "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document",
      "cpf:location": "C:/Users/a-bensghir/Downloads/P_D_F/output.docx"
    }
  }
}"""

resp = requests.post(url=URL, headers=headers, json=json.dumps(j), files=myfile)
   

print(resp.text)
print(resp.status_code)
```

The status of the code is **400**
I am tho well authentified by the server
But I get the following as a result of `print(resp.text)` :

```
{"requestId":"the_request_id","type":"Bad Request","title":"Not a multipart request. Aborting.","status":400,"report":"{\"error_code\":\"INVALID_MULTIPART_REQUEST\"}"}
```

I think that I have problems understanding the "form parameters" from the Adobe Guide concerning POST method for the EXPORT job of the API (https://documentcloud.adobe.com/document-services/index.html).

Would you have any ideas for improvement. thank you !

Comment: Two form parameters should be declared as per the Adobe guide (contentAnalyserRequests called "j" in my code and that is a json, and  <file_content_part_name> that I didn't introduce in my code because I don't know how). Could you please help? thanks !

Comment: So I am _very_ new to Python, but are you sure you are creating a multipart request correctly? The error seems to imply you are not.

Comment: For example, maybe this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15785071/52160

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make you variable `j` as a python `dict` first then create a JSON string from it.
What's also not super clear from Adobe's documentation is the value for `documentIn.cpf:location` needs to be the same as the key used for you file. I've corrected this to `InputFile0` in your script. Also guessing you want to save your file so I've added that too.

```
import requests
import json
import time

URL = "https://cpf-ue1.adobe.io/ops/:create?respondWith=%257B%2522reltype%2522%253A%2520%2522http%253A%252F%252Fns.adobe.com%252Frel%252Fprimary%2522%257D"

headers = {
    'Authorization': f'Bearer {token}',
    'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
    'x-api-key': client_id,
    'Prefer': "respond-async,wait=0",
}

myfile = {"InputFile0":open("absolute_path_to_the_pdf_file/input.pdf", "rb")}

j={
  "cpf:engine": {
    "repo:assetId": "urn:aaid:cpf:Service-26c7fda2890b44ad9a82714682e35888"
  },
  "cpf:inputs": {
    "params": {
      "cpf:inline": {
        "targetFormat": "docx"
      }
    },
    "documentIn": {
      "dc:format": "application/pdf",
      "cpf:location": "InputFile0"
    }
  },
  "cpf:outputs": {
    "documentOut": {
      "dc:format": "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document",
      "cpf:location": "C:/Users/a-bensghir/Downloads/P_D_F/output.docx"
    }
  }
}

body = {"contentAnalyzerRequests": json.dumps(j)}

resp = requests.post(url=URL, headers=headers, data=body, files=myfile)
   

print(resp.text)
print(resp.status_code)

poll = True
while poll:
    new_request = requests.get(resp.headers['location'], headers=headers)
    if new_request.status_code == 200:
        open('test.docx', 'wb').write(new_request.content)
        poll = False
    else:
        time.sleep(5)
```

Comment: Thank you! I took in account these suggestions. Then I got the following message for Print(resp.text) :    {"requestId":"aSeriesOfLetters","type":"Bad Request","title":"Not a multipart request. Aborting.","status":400,"report":"{\"error_code\":\"INVALID_MULTIPART_REQUEST\"}"}

Comment: Make sure you're using the `data` attribute in the `requests.post` and not `json`.

Comment: Sorry bout that, you're right there's a second request to get the doc.

Comment: Now it's working well! thanks! I still have a problem.. I don't know why the docx file (its well created by the way) doesn't open, telling via popup that the content is not readable. maybe it's due to the `` 'wb' `` parsing methos

Comment: Try with a polling mechanism. You might be getting caught out with requesting the doc before it's ready. See edit.

Comment: Make another question with the changed code.

Answer (score 1):

> I don't know why the docx file (its well created by the way) doesn't open, telling via popup that the content is not readable. maybe it's due to the `'wb'` parsing methos

I had the same issue. Typecasting to 'bytes' the request contents solved it.

```
poll = True
    while poll:
        new_request = requests.get(resp.headers['location'], headers=headers)
        if new_request.status_code == 200:
            with open('test.docx', 'wb') as f:
                f.write(bytes(new_request.content))
            poll = False
        else:
            time.sleep(5)
```