# python http client module handle http multipart response?

Tags: python, http

I'm looking for python http client module which can receive and output http multi-part response. The built-in http.client doesn't help.

I'm expecting the http client module which can handle tcp stream de-fragmentation and output parts of http response.

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Kevin Kuei

Comment: Maybe here it can help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15767785/python-http-multipart-form-data-post-request
from what I am reading there, it is maybe not in power of built-in http.client

Comment: Thank you. But the post you mention is for HTTP request, not for http multiple-part response.